# Как уменьшить размер приложения после добавления AdMob? Android

Tags: admob, android

Приложение весит 3.07 мб, после добавления рекламы admob стало 6.96 мб

Потом в gradle.build я изменил строку:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
```

на:

```
сompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:6.+'
```

И приложение стало весить 5.15 Мб, можно ещё как-то уменьшить его размер?

Comment: а оно после этого точно работает?

Comment: да, я проверял

Answer (score 1):

Вот нашёл очень хороший способ, моё приложение стало 2.73 мб - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978356/how-to-reduce-app-size-increased-after-admob-ads